# Is this some viral / disease on my plant?

Tags: identification, diseases, transplanting, fungus

I planted this 4 weeks ago and now I see that the plan developed a couple of these spots as you can see in the picture.[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say you 'planted' this 4 weeks ago, it appears to be still in a pot ,, and it looks like the pot has been pushed into the ground  - is that correct? Is there a label with the plant that gives a varietal name? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: Lol. Nope I just cut the rim as I had placed copper tape on the pot to deter snails when I bought this plant and wanted to keep that barrier.

Comment: I also dug down like two and a half feet by two and a half feet and amended the soil with 50/50 of native and Dr, Earth. Don't really think I have to do that but I figured adding better soil to good is always better....?

Comment: I'm in South NJ and forgot the name of this plant

Comment: So it's confirmed it's a mountain laurel.... So now what's the verdict, regarding these spots

Comment: My apologies - it isn't Pieris! That;s what you get for answering something when you're in the middle of a migraine...  okay, so now you're certain this is Kalmia latifolia, or mountain laurel?  That's probably accurate, because it isnt Photinia either...will alter my original answer.

Comment: Deleted my answer as Kalmia latifolia is correct and @Bamboo's answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I originally mistook this plant for Pieris, you've now confirmed its Kalmia latifolia, common name Sheep Laurel or Mountain Laurel. The new leaves appear to be pinkish red in colour, so it might be the variety Kalmia 'Olympic Fire'.  Like Pieris, they require acidic soil, so hopefully, you've been able to provide that. The plant looks pretty healthy other than the leaf spot, which is most likely fungal in origin, though I'm not too happy about the plant pot rim left around the top. When planting into the ground, it's important that the plant is placed at the same level in the soil as it was in the pot - the rim you've left means the top part is isolated from the surrounding soil rather than being buried in it, and that might compromise its health. These plants are not particularly susceptible to slug and snail damage anyway, so the copper tape is likely unnecessary, so I'd recommend you remove the top of the pot and reposition the plant if necessary.

Kalmia does suffer from a fungal leaf spot which is specific to them (Cercospora kalmiae) and that is most  likely what you're seeing here. It is important the plant is not watered using overhead irrigation, but rather the water is applied direct to the soil around the plant, avoiding the leaves - wet leaves encourages this fungal infection. I'm afraid you will need to use a suitable fungicide, if you have any available where you are https://extension.psu.edu/mountain-laurel-diseases

Comment: The plant was removed from the pot  before I replanted and the rim is just laying there on top of the soil.  I made sure it didn't compromise the replanting process. if you think that this will make a difference regarding protecting the plans from snails or that snails don't harm this plant then I'll remove it

Comment: If you planted it properly first, then just placed the rim on the top of the soil, it won't cause any problems.

Comment: thank you so much for updating your post and I will try to get a fungicide and make sure I don't get water on the leaves

Comment: Any recommendations on a fungicide

Comment: Not really, other than trying copper sprays if  you can get them there - I'm in the UK and there are no effective fungicides available for amateur use, though there may be in the USA. Some information on natural measures here https://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/plant-disease/bacterial-leaf-spot/

Comment: What's your thoughts on this one.....Bonide chemical 772 number-4 copper dust fungicide

Comment: I found something else re leafspot on Kalmia https://homeguides.sfgate.com/mountain-laurel-leaves-turning-yellow-brown-falling-off-94227.html where it says to use a wettable product containing benomyl, so looking for one of those is probably your best bet, since Kalmia gets more than one type of leaf spot.

Comment: Wear protective gear when using any fungicide though, please - they've been banned for amateur use in Europe because they were all pretty  much carcinogenic, especially if breathed in. You may need ot clear away the mulch from around the plant too - fungal spores will be  sitting in that over winter.